# ATG Form handling - Form values getting retained on successful submission

Tags: atg

In ATG form Handling, i have a scenario, where the success and error URL are same? This Formhandler is for creating/Editing/Deleting the Gift certificate.

When ever we add a Gift certificate entering all the fields in the page, it gets added to the cart? but the form fields are getting retained in the input fields? It should get retained only in case of error in validation, but on success it should remove all the user enter fields in the input fields.

i cannot set value="", as this will fail in error flow where i need to show the user entered values along with the invalid field data entered.

Do we need to manually reset the values to empty string or is there any better way?

Please suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Is your form handler session scoped? If you do not need the values post submission in the form handler input fields, you can make it request scoped, the values will be cleared after the request is handled.

If you are saying the fields are stored even when your form handler is session scoped, I would like to know how that is happening.

If you want to display the incorrect entry by the user, add it to the form Exceptions with the formatted message, so you don't need it later.

Hope this helps.